# how to access array name in json2html, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json2html

I have Following working code:

```
var transforms = {
   'renderTimeline':[  {
       tag: "a",  
       class: "btn btn-warning btn-circle", 
       style: "float: right;", 
       html: "<i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>",
       "onclick": function(e) {
       delSchedule(e);
     }}
  }]
}
```

If I am passing the following json :

```
{ monday:[ { startTime:10:00, endTime: 12:00, room_id:cse124 }, { startTime:13:00, endTime: 15:00, room_id:lotus } ] }
```

And I invoke the transform like this :

```
$('#someplace').json2html(data.monday, transforms.renderTimeline, {'events': true});
```

I want to be able to access "monday" in the function delSchedule(). How do i do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not json. It's native `Object`

```
"onclick": function(e) {
    var obj = {
        monday: [{
            startTime: 10: 00,
            endTime: 12: 00,
            room_id: cse124
        }, {
            startTime: 13: 00,
            endTime: 15: 00,
            room_id: lotus
        }]
    };
    delSchedule(obj.monday); // pass it here
}
```

If it is *in* JSON, then it's no big deal. Just do `delSchedule(JSON.parse(jsonStr).monday)`

Comment: Well I am reading a json object and cannot hardcode like you mentioned.

Comment: _If I am passing the following json_...but you have not mentioned how?

Comment: @Jai :

Like this :

    $('#someplace').json2html(data.monday, transforms.renderTimeline, {'events': true});

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to parse the Json by using jQuery.parseJSON(). Then it will return an object.

var jObject = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);

var monday = jObject.monday;

Comment: Are you sure your data is ready to be accessed in delSchedule function? Are you making any asynchronous call to get data?

Comment: yes. im sure. data is being rendered as html and all other things work.  I print out the event using Console.log() in delSchedule().

Comment: console.log(myevent.obj) inside delSchedule() gives me : 
Object { startTime:10:00, endTime: 12:00, room_id:cse124 }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [json2html.com](http://json2html.com) it describes the available properties of the "e" parameter you're passing to delSchedule(e) in Attributes->jquery->Event Attributes

[image]

And to answer your question your delSchedule should look like so

```
function delSchedule(e) {
     console.log( e.obj );
}
```

What will e.obj return?  That depends on what JSON object you're transforming.  For example

```
$('#someplace').json2html(data, transforms.renderTimeline);
```

would create one  element and

```
e.obj === { monday:[ { startTime:10:00, endTime: 12:00, room_id:cse124 }, { startTime:13:00, endTime: 15:00, room_id:lotus } ] }
```

with

```
$('#someplace').json2html(data.monday, transforms.renderTimeline);
```

would create two  elements and each one would have

```
e.obj === { startTime:10:00, endTime: 12:00, room_id:cse124 }
e.obj === { startTime:13:00, endTime: 15:00, room_id:lotus }
```

FYI you're transform doesn't need the events:true option .. that's only if your using the json2html.transform function directly